# How to concatenate input value with an existing array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add the user's text into an existing array. Currently, as you type each character they get added as a separate value in the array.

My question is how can you group these multiple values to form a single value. e.g. I type 'Hello World' into the input and the array should look like:

```
['red', 'green', 'blue', 'Hello World']
```

Currently, it looks like:

```
['red', 'green', 'blue', 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

I'd like to recreate the type and search functionality similar to that being used on the fontawesome.com website, see links below.

Eventually I'd like to push checkbox values (representing categories) into the same array, looping though to display these categories and the search term entered, inside an unordered list. However I need to somehow combine the users search term into a single string first.

Thanks in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/tduv7mf0/3/
https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Website</title>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="search">

</body>
<script>

let searchString = '';
let array = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

document.querySelector('#search').addEventListener('input', function (event) {
  searchString = event.target.value;
  array.push(searchString);
  console.log(array);
});

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: In which condition you want to insert the value into the array?

Comment: on input change, you are adding the value into the array. that will increase the length of the array on each change

Comment: If there is only one input field and you want to add its value at the end of the array, try this- array[array.length-1] += searchString;

Comment: @SajeebAhamed - you've asked a very good question and I haven't thought about that at all to be honest (I'm new to JavaScript). However maybe using a setTimeout function perhaps? so if the user hasn't pressed a key in more than 2 secs for example then do something. How would you approach this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question. This was a rendering issue on my part rather than a data issue. In my head I thought it would be more efficient to append the user's search to the array, then loop through each value all in one go. Then display each value as `<li>` tags as part of an unordered list.

However I took a different (possibly less efficient, still learning) approach to get the job done.

I have setup a few if / else if statements to check whether or not `searchString.length > 0` and `array.length > 0` equals true. Depending on which one is true or whether both return true, I clear my `<ul>` called tagsContainer `tagsContainer.innerHTML = ''` and fire two functions, shown below:

```
let showSearchText = function () {
    tagsContainer.innerHTML += buildTags(searchText);
}

let showSelectedCategories = function () {
    array.forEach(function (colour) {
        tagsContainer.innerHTML += buildTags(colour);
    });
}
```

Using `+=` appends the returned `<li>` tag from the buildTags function. So now both values appear inside the same unordered list.

Answer (score 0):

The `input` event is fired with each letter typed in.  You can change this to `search` and change your input. type to `search` too.  Now when the input is "submitted" it will use the whole search term together and not each letter...  Change to below:

```js
let searchString = '';
const array = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

document.querySelector('#search').addEventListener('search', function (event) {
  searchString = event.target.value;
  array.push(searchString);
  console.log(array);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Website</title>
</head>

<body>

<input type="search" id="search">

</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: your array can use `const` since the type `array` is not changing (just adding to the existing array).

Comment: Hi @mikerojas please look at the response I made to Sajeeb Ahamed below. Hopefully it'll help explain what I'm trying to achieve a bit clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
let searchString = '';
let array = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
var x = document.getElementById("search");
x.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
  if (event.isComposing || event.keyCode === 13) {
    searchString = event.target.value;
  array.push(searchString);
  alert(searchString );
  }

});

</script>
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, event.isComposing returns false. How do I get it to return true? Never used that property before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it relates to your problem or not. But in most cases, the search works like this. You can try this:

```js
// Assume this is the colors array where you want to make the search
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'white', 'blue', 'purple', 'lime', 'yellow', 'cyan'];


// This function is responsible to render your contents
function renderColors(colors) {
  const listElement = document.querySelector('#colors');
  
  // For every call of the function reset the ul contents
  listElement.innerHTML = '';
  
  colors.forEach(color => {
    listElement.innerHTML += `<li>${color}</li>`;
  });
}

renderColors(colors);


/**
 * This is the search function. This will search your colors at every
 * key press. Because running the search at every key press is not a
 * good job so we can use a little timeout to grab the search keywords
 * at every 200 ms. 
*/
function searchColor() {
  
  const inputElement = document.querySelector('#search');
  const keywordElement = document.querySelector('#keyword');
  
  inputElement.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    
    const searchRegex = new RegExp(value, 'i');
    let timeout;
    
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      keyword.innerHTML = `Search results for "${value}": `;
      const filteredColor = colors.filter(color => searchRegex.test(color));
      renderColors(filteredColor);
    }, 200);

  })
  
}

searchColor();
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search Color" />
<div id="keyword"></div>
<ul id="colors"></ul>
```

Comment: Hi @SajeebAhamed - In the example you've (kindly) provided you're filtering the array of colours. Instead I would like to type a colour e.g. 'pink' into the input and append the input value to the array. As I start to delete characters from the input, the value pushed in also updates.

Comment: Then you have to decide when you have to push the colour into the array. Is it when you type a colour and hit tab key or get out of the field, or when you write your color and hit enter. Or you have a button to insert the color into the array. You really need to decide it.

Comment: Thanks for responding. My inspiration is from the fontawesome.com website. Here they don't use a button event. If you type 'acorn' for example, as you start typing you instantly start to get search results as well as the word you typed. In addition, if you select a category on the left, the name of category appears next to your search text. This is the behaviour that I am trying to replicate. I want to display the user search next to the categories they selected. If the user deletes their search then show just the categories and vise versa. Thanks.

Comment: Fontawesome uses some technique that I've shown you. But they use advanced searching technology and they do it with the help of `algolia` for their search. See the url while you are searching. I've updated my code a little bit. you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>

<html  ng-app="Employeemanagement">
<head>
  
</head>

<body>
  
<input type="text" id="search">

<script>

let searchString = '';
let array = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
var x = document.getElementById("search");
x.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
  if (event.isComposing || event.keyCode === 13) {
    searchString = event.target.value;
  array.push(searchString);
  test();
  }

});
function test()
{
alert(array);
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```